# React's onMouseMove working on div but not on custom component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to record, whenever the user moves the mouse over my `<Canvas />` Component, and console log the coordinates.

This works:

```
<div onMouseMove={this._onMouseMove.bind(this)}>
  <Canvas 
    dataURL={this.state.image} 
    textTop={this.state.textTop} 
    textBottom={this.state.textBottom} 
    fontSize={this.state.fontSize} />
  </div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't (moving the `onMouseMove` from the `div` onto the `Canvas Component` itself):

```
<div>
  <Canvas 
    onMouseMove={this._onMouseMove.bind(this)}
    dataURL={this.state.image} 
    textTop={this.state.textTop} 
    textBottom={this.state.textBottom} 
    fontSize={this.state.fontSize} />
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**PS:** Just to be complete:

```
_onMouseMove(e) {
    console.log(e.screenX);
    console.log(e.screenY);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onMouseMove` will just be like any other prop that your custom component has to handle itself.

**Example**

```
class Canvas extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <canvas onMouseMove={this.props.onMouseMove} />;
  }
}
```